# Using Overtone in Jython / Clojure Dependencies in Jython

Tags: java, clojure, dependencies, jython, leiningen

I'm currently working on a project that primarily uses Jython, but makes use of interop (using rik0's [pyclj](https://github.com/rik0/pyclj) solution) with Clojure to utilize the [Overtone](http://overtone.github.com) library. Typically, leiningen is the primary way of handling dependencies for projects, but since I'm mostly using Jython, I doubt it will help with handling the dependencies when using it. Right now my current solution is to compile to a jar using lein and then include the jars in the classpath with

```
    jython -J-cp <path-to-jar>
```

However, when I try to start up Overtone from Jython, I get the error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'scsynth': dlopen(libscsynth.dylib, 9): image not found
```

This is a resource that is supplied by Overtone and is listed in the manifest of files in the jar. I assume this means that either just having the jar on the classpath isn't sufficient for including resources packaged in the jar like dylibs, or that it's something to do with the fact that the Jython files aren't compiled and resolved in the lein build.

How would I go about properly resolving these resource dependencies between Jython and Clojure?

EDIT:

So I was able to get it to work using a hacky solution found from [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/overtone/vhfd1eH5pL0) Google Groups post by setting the dynamic library path to the path where libscsynth.dylib is located before running Jython. Preferably, I'd like a less hacky way of doing this, but in the meantime this should suffice. If anyone has any idea how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Looks like I'm experiencing the same problem as you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57909082/198927. Are you on OSX?